# Is there a variation of Madhurashtakam with Mathura in it?

Tags: krishna, stotra, vallabhacharya

*Madhurashtakam* is an eight versed chant composed by [Vallabhacharya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vallabha) composed on Lord Krishna. It describes about the beauty of Lord Krishna. In the stotra, Vallbhacharya says everything about Lord Krishna is sweet. The last line of every stanza is common. It is

> **मधुराधिपतेरखिलम् मधुरम्**
>
> **Madhurādhipaterakhilam madhuram**

But I also saw some people use **Mathurādhipate** (मथुराधिपते). While I was listening to this stotra on [YouTube](https://youtu.be/t_KcX_TTYcM), Sri Krishna is called as Madhuradhipati. But he is the lord of Mathura. So, I thought it should be Mathurādhipate. They added an important note before starting a video.

[image]

I wouldn't take the YouTube channel because they have been sincere about pronunciation of stotras and they said that they consulted Sanskrit scholars before making the Video.

My questions are below (interrelated):

- What did Vallabhacharya originally call Krishna in the stotra, Mathurathipathi (lord of Mathura) or Madhuradhipathi (Lord of Sweetness)?
- Is there a rendering where the other variation of this stotra?
- Did Vallabhacharya use Madhuradhipathi to match the chhandas and alankara rules of Sanskrit?

Comment: It wouldn't make any difference for the chandas because both *dha* and *tha* are *mahAprANa* and there is no addition or deletion of other sounds.

Comment: Mathura is the Hindi (Braj) name for Madhura (Sanskrit) or Madhupuri (named after Madhu, father of Lavanasura). That’s why Mathura is referred to as VadaMadurai and Madurai is referred to as ThenMadurai when we want to differentiate.